Прописывать глобальные переменные в строчке
define('URL_SITE', "https://site.ru");

echo "text ".URL_SITE." text";

Возможно глобальные переменные прописывать в строке. Без кавычек с точками, как с переменными к примеру
echo "text {$site} text";


Это константа, а не переменная и нет, нельзя

Увы, пока ещё такое невозможно.

@Simon, ответы - в ответы.
